# Drilldown for lines in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, jsfiddle, lines, drilldown

Is there any way I wcould use drill down list for line in highcharts. I tried the demo in JSFiddle...but the main chart does not connect to each other while the drilldown list connects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/

Then, what you need to do is set the `type` to 'line':

```
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
```

That gets you part of the way. The issue of the points not being connected by the line is due to the series option:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: brandsData
        }],
```

Remove `colorByPoint` option and the line is drawn between points. You are then left with a line chart with both primary and drilled down series being 'line' type.  If you don't want each series to be a line you can assign individual types in the `series` properties.

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/qnLm12vj/).